# Rounding the value to the nearest 50

Tags: sql-server, rounding

I am trying to round down the value to the nearest 50.
1-50 it should round down to below 00 and when its 51-rest then it should round down to 50

ex:

- 245 (until 1-49) its should round down to 200
- 258 (from 50-99)then it should round down  to 250

I tried this,its wrking good but I need smething other than case statement

```
@ResultAmount = ROUND(@ResultAmount, -2, 1) + 
    CASE    WHEN RIGHT(CONVERT(INT, FLOOR(@ResultAmount)), 2) IN (00, 50)
            THEN RIGHT(CONVERT(INT, FLOOR(@ResultAmount)), 2)
            WHEN RIGHT(CONVERT(INT, FLOOR(@ResultAmount)), 2) BETWEEN 1 AND 49
            THEN 00
            WHEN RIGHT(CONVERT(INT, FLOOR(@ResultAmount)), 2) BETWEEN 51 AND 99
            THEN 50
            END
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just divide your number by 50 (num / 50), if result 'R' is Odd and remainder(num % 50) is gt 0, then (R+1) * 50, otherwise R * 50

Comment: Am I reading this right? 1-50 should round *up* to 50, 245 rounds *down* to 200 but then 258 rounds *up* again to 300? What is the logic for up/down?

Comment: @Jamiec Ithink is the same as `2.45` is round to `2` but `2.55` round up to `3`

Comment: @Jamiec But you are right the nearest 50 of `245` is `250`, not `200`

Comment: So basically any value with the pattern `*5x - *9x` should round to `*50`, and any value with `*0x - *4x` should round to `*00` ? 1073 to 1050, 1023 to 1000, etc.? What about exact multiples of 50? Like 50? Keep it at 50 or go down to 0?

Comment: Yes!! exactly I have to do the same !! 1073 to 1050, 1023 to 1000!!!!

Comment: surely you would round 50 to 50 - but you have sad that you want to round 01-50 to 00 - what do you want to do with 00?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is all you need

```
SELECT FLOOR(@ResultAmount / 50) * 50;
```

e.g below

```
declare @ResultAmount decimal(10,2) = 249;

SELECT FLOOR(@ResultAmount / 50) * 50;

SET @ResultAmount = 250;

SELECT FLOOR(@ResultAmount / 50) * 50;

SET @ResultAmount = 200;

SELECT FLOOR(@ResultAmount / 50) * 50;

SET @ResultAmount = 199;

SELECT FLOOR(@ResultAmount / 50) * 50;
```

Comment: One thing to note is that this is for rounding DOWN (which is what OP asked for).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like numbers 0-50 get rounded up to "50", but any number larger than that should just get rounded to the nearest 50. Something like the following should work:

```
(CASE WHEN f1/50 < 1 THEN 1 ELSE ceiling(f1/50) END) * 50 AS rounded_to_50
```

Comment: Why not check `f1` against 50 and return 50?

Comment: Yea.. I dunno. I guess `(CASE WHEN f1 <= 50 THEN 50 ELSE ceiling(f1/50)*50 END) AS rounded_to_50` would probably save a cpu cycle or two. There may be some boolean math that would be quicker then the case statement too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply divide the number by 50, round then multiply by 50 again, eg:

```
select cast(round(@i/50.0,0)*50 as int)
```

This will return 500 if `@i` is 524 but 550 if `@i` is 525.

You can create a function to make this easier:

```
create function fn_Round_By(@input int,@divider float) 
returns int
as
begin 
    RETURN (cast(round(@input/@divider,0)*@divider as int));
end
```

Again, `select dbo.fn_Round_By(525,50)` returns `550 and`select dbo.fn_Round_By(524,50)` returns 500.

If you want values less than 50 to round *up* to 50, you can use a simple `CASE`, eg:

```
create function fn_Round_By(@input int,@divider float) 
returns int
as
begin 
    RETURN (
        CASE 
            WHEN @input <=@divider then @divider
            else cast(round(@input/@divider,0)*@divider as int)
        END
        );
end
```

Rounding down is performed by the [FLOOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx) function so a function that rounded down to a specific interval would be:

```
create function fn_Floor_By(@input int,@divider float) 
returns int
as
begin 
    RETURN (cast(FLOOR(@input/@divider)*@divider as int));
end
```

or, preserving the logic that rounds up anything under 50:

```
create function fn_Floor_By(@input int,@divider float) 
returns int
as
begin 
    RETURN (
        CASE 
            WHEN @input <=@divider then @divider
            else cast(FLOOR(@input/@divider)*@divider as int)
        END
        );
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help a small correction !! its lke It should always round down..lke if it is 230 it should round 200 and if it is 260 or 280 it should round to 250!!

Comment: Rounding down is performed by the `FLOOR` function,  but your examples contradict each other, eg 230 should be truncated to 200 but 258 should become 300 yet 260 becomes 250? What exactly *is* the logic you want?

Comment: I want to perform round down lke if its 230 its should round down to 200 and if it is 258 or 280 (anything between 51-99) it should round down to 250!!! thanks

Comment: @kris please fix the question text then and make it clear that you want to round *down*.

Comment: I've already added functions that use `FLOOR` to the answer. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate modulo 50 and use this to reduce the original value

```
DECLARE @ResultAmount int = 243

SELECT @ResultAmount - (@ResultAmount%50)
```